# How to enable ATI 48xx in Mavericks (tried with Multibeast but no use)

Tags: resolution, amd-radeon, kext

I managed to install Maverick 10.9 - but the Graphics is not detecting my ATI 4890 Cyclone 1GB.

How do I enable it ?

I tried various options:

- Install the kexts using [Multibeast 6.2.1](http://www.tonymacx86.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=219)
- boot with `-GraphicsEnabler=Yes` option.
- Edit the `/Extra/org.chameleon.Boot.plist` to include these keys:

  `<key>Graphics Mode</key>
  <string>1920x1080x32</string>`
- Edit the `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.Boot.plist` file to include these keys:

  `<key>Graphics Mode</key>
  <string>1920x1080x32</string>`

None of these options worked. I'm stuck at 1400x1050@32 resolution.

Anyone can share how to get full HD (1920x1080x32) resolution on Maverick Hackintosh ?

Answer (score 0):

Try GraphicsEnabler=Yes IGPEnabler=No . To enable full hd resolution see this post http://www.tonymacx86.com/hp-probook-mavericks/114048-how-patch-dsdt-full-hd-screen.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but note that I've tried `GraphicsEnabler=Yes` (see my question), and I do not have Intel HD so `IGPEnabler=No` do not make sense.

Comment: http://www.niresh12495.com/topic/728-ati-radeon-hd-5670-on-mavericks/